# in Java Programming, will the file (.txt, .ser etc) get overwritten when we rewrite on existing file?

Tags: java

if I Do like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("cse.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(Dictionary);
```

and Again if I write the same file using the another object of Same type Dictionary on the same file like

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("cse.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(List);
```

Will that file get overwritten ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write simply:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("cse.txt");
```

Then the old data will be lost and will get overridden by the new data.

However, if you write:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("cse.txt", true);
```

Then the old data will **NOT** be lost and the new data will be appended to the old one.

Here, the second argument `true` indicates that the bytes will be appended to the end of the file rather than overwriting the complete file.

[See the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean))